# How to manually add Sims 3 to Origin Launcher when already installed?

Tags: the-sims-3

I installed Sims 3 a few years ago and I didn't play it for a year, so Origin needed to update. I also needed to log in to my Origin account, but I don't know my email, password or ID anymore, so I made a new one, but that account doesn't have Sims 3 in the launcher. Since it was already installed earlier, I can add this manually, but I don't know which file I should pick to launch the game.

Edit: When I search in The Sims 3\Game\Bin, this is what I get, I know it's not Sims3, that's the icon. I'm Dutch, so everything on the picture will be in Dutch.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I dont have Sims 3 installed at the moment, but it works the same way as other Origin games. The file you want is the .exe file.

The game folder is located under (as default): C:\Program Files (x86)\Origin Games
Once you are in the Sims 3 game folder look for an .exe file called Sims3 (or similar). That's the file that launches the game.
Hope this answer was of any use. If you have any questions leave a comment.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but the problem is, there are many .exe files and I don't which one.

Comment: @WoutHuygens can you take a screenshot?

Comment: Added it to my question.

Comment: It's the one simply called Sims3